# Jsp,Js Changes not reflecting

Tags: arrays, jsp

I am trying to make changes in jsp in my project in jdeveloper on struts1 framework.

changes in existing jsps are not getting reflected.

Comment: Try to go to the folder of the compiled jsp (under `project-tomcat/work/catalina/...`) and manually delete the compiled `.java` and `.class` files.

Comment: I am testing it on jdevelopers default embedded oc4j server